# How to use same scss variable in different divs with different value?

Tags: css, sass

I have a variable

```
$height: 40px;
```

Now, I used this as

```
.exmp{
    height: $height;
}
```

Now, I want to use the variable in other class

```
.exmp2{
   height: $height;  // here the height must be different. I want to keep 100px
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with just setting 100px there?

Comment: `exmp`, `exmp2` are just parent sections. I have so many styles which uses the height variable. I can't change change height for each child elements

Comment: I prefer to access the variable using a function instead of accessing directly. Inside the function, you implement a multiplier logic and return the processed value. eg: `f(x):  10 * x` where 10 is the base height and x is the multiplier.

Comment: Can you please explain this. Or write your code in the answer

Comment: max-height: 100px;